# Nginx: referring too-large files uploads to application?

Tags: symfony, nginx, file-upload

I need to be able to deal with uploaded files sizes exceeding the maximum nginx and php limits before nginx issues an error 413 page. Instead, I want to issue an error message within my application (symfony) dialog.

To test the file-size limits in symfony, My test upload file is 600 Mb. When I upload the 600 Mb file under nginx, the upload runs to 100%, then 
reports "*413 Request Entity Too Large*".

If I run "app/console server:run" (which uses the symfony server instead of nginx), symfony reports the error in the gui before the upload occurs (as intended).

Is there any way to modify the nginx configuration so it reads the $_SERVER[CONTENT_LENGTH] or $_SERVER[HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH], aborts the upload, and then passes the rejected request to the app? Symfony flags the error depending on CONTENT_LENGTH (and, with a work-around for a symfony issue, HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH).

File size limits:

```
src/my_app/CoreBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml: maxSize: '500M'
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini:post_max_size = 550M
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 500M
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 550M
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 500M
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 550M
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

Versions:

```
symfony 2.5.12  
nginx 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the allowed size in the nginx config http block.

```
client_max_body_size 800m;
```

Set a value thats higher then the value in your php.ini. Then the nginx server dont response with 413 and symfony shows the normal error page because of the php limitation.

Comment: Thanks, Crofly.

Increasing the limit means that it takes longer for the same issue to happen with >800Mb files. I need to be able to catch the issue before the upload starts.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by catching changes in the file selection in javascript, then popping up a warning and clearing the selection if the file is too large.

My hunch is that nginx doesn't parse the incoming request in any way, ie, it doesn't read CONTENT_LENGTH or HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH, and rejects the request purely based on whether the size of the request exceeds client_max_body_size. If that's true (confirmation or denial would be great), then there's no way to deal with this when using nginx except letting nginx run the upload and encounter the 413 error (which is time-consuming for a large file and/or slow network).

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length will work on non chunked content, however I suspect your upload to be chunked and then there is no way that nginx can find out what the size of your content is. 
Even if it could, it should not pass it.

By HTTP/1.1 specs:
 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt:

```
3.If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
 decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
 transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
 if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
 header field is present). If a message is received with both a
 Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
 the latter MUST be ignored.
```